# What is the function in Python that sort files by extension?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os
import string
os.chdir('C:\Python27')
x=os.listdir('C:\Python27')

y=[f for f in os.listdir(dirname)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, f))]

for k in y:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(k)
    print fileName,fileExtension
```

And now, I want to sort the files by extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the list using a `key` function:

```
y.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.splitext(f))
```

Answer (score 8):

To sort by name, then by extension:

```
y.sort(key=os.path.splitext)
```

It produces the order:

```
a.2
a.3
b.1
```

To sort only by extension:

```
y.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1])
```

It produces the order:

```
b.1
a.2
a.3
```

Comment: Thank You very much, my friends!! I hope that you will have a splendid day;)You helped me a lot:D

Answer (score 0):

without importing os module I think we can write like this. maybe there can be a shorter code but I could find this

```
from typing import List

def sort_by_ext(files: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    extensions = []
    for file in files:
        extensions.append(file.rsplit('.',1)[-1])
    indices = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(extensions)}
    return sorted(files, key=lambda s: indices[s.rsplit('.', 1)[1]], reverse = True)
```